# bind_rows for each result of a function in R

Tags: r, function, rbind

I want to have a data_frame with 1 row for each of my nodes.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)

nodeToDf <- function(theNode) {
  # More complex stuff here. But in the end it returns a data_frame with 1 row
  xml_attrs(theNode) %>%
    map_dfr(~as.list(.))
}  

data <- read_xml("<root><book title='First' pages='100'/><book title='Second' pages='100'/><book title='Third' pages='100'/></root>")
books <- xml_find_all(data, "//book")
map_df(books,nodeToDf)
# Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names
```

So my question is how can I get a data_frame with 1 row for each node in myNodeSet by calling a nodeToDf for each node?

Comment: Can you share a little sample input to make this reproducible? Also it's good to mention the packages you are using. `xml` and `xml2` have different interfaces, and there's probably other packages that handle XML as well. And I can tell you're using `purrr`, but again it's nice to call it out.

Comment: Or better yet include all `library` lines.

Comment: Yes, sorry. This should be executable now

Comment: `bind_rows(nodeToDf(books[1]), nodeToDf(books[2]), nodeToDf(books[3]))` Gives the desired result, but I do not now on frehand how many nodes there will be

Answer (score 1):

try using rbind

```
rbind(myNodeset,nodeToDf)
```

Comment: rbind gives me an error:
    Error in rbind(books, nodeToDf) : 
      cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'

Comment: you have to make sure that both books and nodeToDf have same class  , use "class(books)" and "class(nodeToDf)" in your R console to check that.

Comment: books is an *xml_nodeset* and nodeToDf a *function*

Comment: try"rbind(as.dataframe(xml_attrs(books)),as.dataframe(nodeToDf))"

Comment: The error @BasJansen gets is to be expected. This result is asking you to bind a function and an xml_nodeset. That's not going to work

Answer (score 0):

As the OPs comment says, the following produces the desired result, but s/he doesn't know how many rows there will be:

```
bind_rows(nodeToDf(books[1]), nodeToDf(books[2]), nodeToDf(books[3]))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  title  pages
  <chr>  <chr>
1 First  100  
2 Second 100  
3 Third  100
```

Your function already works with an arbitrary number of rows, see:

```
nodeToDF(books)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  title  pages
  <chr>  <chr>
1 First  100  
2 Second 100  
3 Third  100
```

The last line in your function body `map_dfr(~as.list(.))` does exactly what you're looking for. Takes the elements of the list, and binds them together as rows of a data frame (vs. `map_dfc`, which would bind them as columns).